# Count the total of a grouped by with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
details = { 
    'order_number' : ['#1', '#2', '#3', '#4','#4'], 
    'disc_code' : ['no_discount', 'superman', 'hero', 'numero_uno','numero_uno'], 
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(details)
```

`len(df)` --> 6408  
Each row attributes to one product, instead of one transaction.
If I group every row to each order name, there are 3560 rows.
`len(df.groupby('order_number'))` --> 3560

I want to count **how many discount codes are used in total**. (if no discount code is used, the value is 'no_discount')

In SQL, the syntax probably looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM transactions
GROUP BY order_number
WHERE discount_code != 'no_discount'
```

Comment: groupby.nunique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) if need count per `order_number`:

```
df1 = (df[df['disc_code'].ne('no_discount')]
           .groupby('order_number')
           .size()
           .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
  order_number  count
0           #2      1
1           #3      1
2           #4      2
```

If need count all values only count `True`s values by condition for not equal by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with `sum`:

```
out = df['disc_code'].ne('no_discount').sum()
```

Comment: how to get the total of this dataframe?

Comment: @Luc - Do you think `print (df['count'].sum())` ?

Comment: @Luc - Can you add expected output from sample data?